# max() and min() functions are returning the maximum and minimum index of a list instead of values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I created a list of lengths using the len() function, and it returned a list like this: {0: 101, 1: 101, 2: 101, 3: 100 ... }.
When I use the max() and min() functions to find the index of the list, it simply returns the maximum and mininum index values (0 and n).

I created my lengths list in this way:

```
n = len(df.index)  
lengths = {} 

for i in range(0,n):

    lengths[i] = len(df.at[i,'col'])
```

To find the maximum and minimum I used:

```
maximum = max(lengths)

minimum = min(lengths)
```

which produces an incorrect result.

When I append the list lengths as a column to my dataframe, and use

```
minimum = min(df.loc[:,'lengths'])
```

the result is correct.

What is wrong about my list method?

Comment: When you use a dictionary as a sequence, you get the keys, not the values. So `max(lengths)` returns the maximum key.

Comment: `max(lengths, key=lengths.get)` will return the key with the maximum length.

Comment: ...which is funny, because the key is not the key, but what you get is the key... confused? ;-)